# can gapped systems have gravitational anomalies?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, research-level

The question is in the title.

If it is possible, what are some examples of gapped systems--either quantum field theories or condensed matter systems--which exhibit some kind of anomaly when coupled to a metric with curvature or placed on a spacetime with non-trivial topology?

Comment: Do you mean systems with an energy gap between some electronic excitation levels, like semiconducting silicon? Those sorts of gaps are a feature that arises in momentum space; gravity is a phenomenon of mass distributions in position space.

Comment: I mean systems with an energy gap above the ground state(s), so yes the effective field theory of an electron in an insulating material is gapped.

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): It seems OP is talking about a (non-gravitational) QFT in a fixed curved background. Note that a [gravitational (quantum) anomaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_anomaly) (according to the standard definition, not to be confused with a [gravity anomaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_anomaly)) only occurs in gravity theories with dynamically active metrics.

Comment: A gravitational anomaly is some problem with formulating the field theory on a manifold that isn't Minkowski space. In some sense we are coupling to a background gravitational field.

Comment: @RyanThorngren Out of curiosity, do you have reason to believe that such systems cannot exist?  In other words, I'm basically wondering what motivated this question.

Comment: Some systems have edge modes with robust gaplessness. In the case that this robustness is symmetry protection, then we can explain this by saying the boundary has a 't Hooft anomaly. Sometimes the same argument is made for systems (eg. the E8 state) via a gravitational anomaly for the bulk. Making these arguments rigorous requires understanding which gravitational anomalies (if any) can be realized by gapped theories.

Comment: Separate from the condensed matter motivation, gapped systems are ones whose long range effective field theory is topological. I'm more generally interested in what sorts of anomalies can be realized by topological field theories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my question is Yes.

Embarrassingly, one of the simplest examples is given by the fermionic quasistring topological order I described in my paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.4385 . The magic is that the 5th oriented bordism group is generated by the mapping torus of complex conjugation on CP^2. Thus, if we consider the fermionic quasistring top order on CP^2, the action changes by a sign when we perform the large diffeomorphism of complex conjugation on CP^2.

Comment: I am not sure why this is the simplest example. Any 1+1d chiral fermion /boson on the edge of  the bulk gapped systems have grav anomalies related to the net energy-momentum tensor. Your example is not very clear.

Comment: @user32229 such theories are not gapped.

Answer (score 2):

When one encounters the statement "gapped systems have gravitational anomalies", I think the precise statement is that

> "gapped systems with **[bulk topological order (read the link Review)](http://dao.mit.edu/~wen/topartS3.pdf)** have **boundary gravitational anomalies**".

So the answer to your question is **yes, if we look into the surface of the bulk topological order.**

Three papers you may look at are that:

1. [Classifying gauge anomalies through SPT orders and classifying gravitational anomalies through topological orders](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.1803)
2. [Braided fusion categories, gravitational anomalies, and the mathematical framework for topological orders in any dimensions](http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.5858)
3. [A field theory representation of pure gauge and mixed gauge-gravity symmetry-protected topological invariants, group cohomology and beyond](http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.7689)

Some examples given above mentioned that gravitational anomalies exist on the boundary of bulk topological order **in any dimension**.

The first question you will ask is that "isn't that Alvarez-Gaumé and Witten said [Gravitational anomalies](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/055032138490066X)
 only exists in **(4n+2)D** spacetime dimension?"

My best response is that Alvarez-Gaumé-Witten talked about **perturbative gravitational anomalies**.

If one consider **non-perturbative or global gravitational anomalies**:
The topological order implies (1) nontrivial SL$(N,\mathbb{Z})$ representation through modular SL$(N,\mathbb{Z})$ transformation. (example in 2+1D [SL$(2,\mathbb{Z})$](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5121) and 3+1D SL$(3,\mathbb{Z})$ with Ref [here on  Modular SL(3,$\mathbb{Z}$) Representation and 3+1D Twisted Gauge Theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.7854) and [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.1062)) and [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.4618); this either implies
(2) the spatial-topology-dependent robust ground state degeneracy(GSD) (such GSD depends on the genus of Riemann surface or the Betti number of the manifold, or [degeneracy with gapped boundaries here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.4863) and [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.4254)) or (3) chiral edge modes.
Intuitively, the topology-dependent robust GSD indicates the existence of **global gravitational anomalies**, but more precisely how it coincides with the HEP work of [Witten](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103943444), we may have to dig into this further. But the basic observation is heuristic and simple.

Comment: I'm confused by this. Certainly there are systems without topological order whose edge states have an associated gravitational anomaly, like the Kitaev $E_8$ state or CS theory at $k=1$. Also there are topologically ordered systems where the edge states don't have a gravitational anomaly, like the toric code. There the edge is non-chiral free bosons and can be generically gapped out. I don't see how gravitational anomalies are generic features of topological order.

Comment: I was also confused before. But the claim (at least by the [Ref](http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.5858) is that even the naive $Z_2$ toric code has edge gravitational anomaly - even if it is gappable.) The gappable statement is that for **free fermion system** if introducing a quadratic mass term can gap the system, then there is no gravitational anomaly.

Comment: For toric code, on one hand it is bosonic, on the other hand it is gappable by introducing the interaction terms sine-Gordon cosine (by bosonization it induces massive Thirring model $(\bar{\psi} \gamma_\mu \psi)^2$), which is NOT the quadratic mass term of fermions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does not yet answer my question, though. In these examples it is the boundary which has a gravitational anomaly. My analogous question for these sorts of gravitational anomalies is "which topological orders admit gapped boundaries?"

Comment: @ Ryan, if your main question is "which topological orders admit gapped boundaries?" then you should ask another question on this. It will be too involved to comment so many things in an answer.

Comment: @Idear Sorry, I misunderstood. That question is more general than mine. If the topological order is to be the anomaly theory for the boundary, then it should be invertible (no topological ground state degeneracy). My question is if any of these admit gapped boundaries.

Comment: $E_8$ state has non-trivial topological order, and its boundary has a perturbative gravitational anomaly.